# How to query other users task history from information_schema.TASK_HISTORY, if both the users tasks are present in the same database and schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm tring to monitor snowflake tasks from information_schema.TASK_HISTORY,
I have as task: TASK_A created by user: USER_A with role: ROLE_A
and another task: TASK_B created by user: USER_B with role: ROLE_B
in a same shared database and schema.

When I query information_schema.TASK_HISTORY from USER_A, I can only see only TASK_A's history.

how can I query both task history's,
What type of privilege or grants I have to give in order to view the combined task history while running the query from one of the user.

Tried giving ownership of TASK_B to ROLE_A but getting the following error
`grantee need to be a subordinate role of the schema owner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is regularly filtered by the permissions available to the role querying it.

Re the INFORMATION_SCHEMA you can see the permissions required to see the data in this view in the docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html#usage-notes):

> Returns results only for the ACCOUNTADMIN role, the task owner (i.e. the role with the OWNERSHIP privilege on the task) or a role with the global MONITOR EXECUTION privilege. Note that unless a role with the MONITOR EXECUTION privilege also has the USAGE privilege on the database and schema that store the task, the DATABASE_NAME and SCHEMA_NAME values in the output are NULL.

If you can cope with the delayed information (up to 45 mins for TASK_HISTORY), the [SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TASK_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/task_history.html) view will have the complete view of all of the tasks executed by all users / roles.

There are a few options here:

1. Grant the MONITOR EXECUTION privilege to ROLE_A and ROLE_B
2. Use the ‘ACCOUNT_USAGE’ views to see all of the history for all tasks but delayed
3. You could grant ROLE_B to ROLE_A or vice versa (this would only work one-way around though otherwise you’d have a circular relationship)
4. Have a role ROLE_C that has ownership of both tasks and then grant ROLE_C to ROLE_A and ROLE_B.

There are probably some other options, but it would be helpful if you could detail your requirements in more detail so that I can provide a better recommendation.

Comment: yes the following options helped me solve the problem statement. Requirement is to run a python job to monitor all the tasks created by different roles and report on failure.  what are the other options you were thinking would like to know those as well.

Comment: Ah ok. For that requirement, I'd recommend Option 1 from my answer then.

For other options... You could potentially surface the information via a stored procedure that you wrote to query with admin privileges and then filter down to what you wanted to present. So if you wanted the python job to only be able to monitor the two tasks and not all other tasks.

I don't think any of the other options I was thinking of would help you.